# Missing Applications folder inside home directory

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

After running Disk Utility from the Snow Leopard disc, the Applications folder inside my home directory became empty or is not linked to the main /Applications folder outside my home directory. How do I restore the Applications folder inside my home?

Comment: ~/Applications is never linked to /Applications - are you sure was this the way you were set up before

Answer (score 1):

The applications folder inside your home directory is not a critical folder; It's purpose is to allow non-administrator users to install applications which they may use when they don't have permissions to write to the `/Applications/` folder.

If you wish to make your personal applications folder point to the global applications folder, then run `ln -s /Applications ~/Applications` in Terminal.

Since this is not the design, I wouldn't be surprised if Apple's repair utilities continue to remove this in the future.